# Rank Nullity Theorem and a Complex of Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$

> Given a complex $0\rightarrow V_0 \rightarrow V_1 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow V_r\rightarrow 0$, write $B_i=\im(V_{i-1} \rightarrow V_i)$ and
>   $Z_i=\ker (V_i \rightarrow V_{i+1})$.
>
> Show $\sum_{i=0}^{i=r}
> (-1)^i \dim V_i=\sum_{i=0}^{i=r} (-1)^i \dim H_i $, where $H_i=Z_i /
> B_i$ is the $i$th homology of the complex.

Here is my work:

Since $V_\cdot$ is a complex, $B_i \subset Z_i$.

Also, $\dim Z_i = \dim B_i + \dim H_i$.

Define $\phi_i:=V_{i-1} \rightarrow V_i$ and $\phi_{i+1}:=V_{i} \rightarrow V_{i+1}$. By rank-nullity theorem,

$$\dim Z_i +\dim(\im \phi_{i+1})=\dim V_i$$

$$\dim (\ker \phi_i) +\dim B_i=\dim V_i.$$

Combining three equations above, I need to show $\dim V_i=\dim (\ker \phi_i)-\dim(\im \phi_{i+1})$. If this approach works, could you give me any hint to continue?

(Thanks to @Michael Hardy for editing my question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume the $V_i$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces?

I do not see any exact sequences here.

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$
You write both
$$\dim Z_i +\dim(\im \phi_{i+1})=\dim V_i.$$
But this says
$$\dim Z_i +\dim B_{i+1}=\dim V_i.\tag{$\dagger$}$$
You also say
$$\dim (\ker \phi_i) +\dim B_i=\dim V_i.$$
But that is incorrect: the right side should be $\dim V_{i-1}$
which is $(\dagger)$ with $i$ replaced by $i-1$.

Now $(\dagger)$ implies
$$\dim H_i+\dim B_i +\dim B_{i+1}=\dim V_i.\tag{$\ddagger$}$$
Multiply $(\ddagger)$ by $(-1)^i$ and add up over all $i$.

Comment: How do you know $\dim B_o$=$0$?

Comment: @VivianL. $B_0$ is the image of a zero homomorphism.